# AD user only needs OWA access and we want to block everything else on the network

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange-2010

We have two domains.  corp and sales.  We are removing the SALES domain and moving all users to the corp domain.  The only thing that the SALES domain did was allow remote sales people to access email.

The problem now is .. Security..

As a result of bringing the sales group over to the corp domain, there is a security issue, now that all sales people have an AD account in the corporate environment.

My question is... can you actually have an AD user and assign them only email rights and no access what so ever to file shares, printers and resource etc?  The only thing they need is OWA access.

Comment: Yes.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The only thing they need is OWA access..

Then why have an AD account? Do they need mailbox space? If not then I would create a contact in Exchange w/ a forwarding address to the address they're likely to check.

Also, you should already have a security in place which *denies* rights to logon to workstations, and those accounts should be *in it*.

Comment: Thanks BigHomie.  They do need mailbox space.  That is the problem.  Otherwise I would have set up the contacts.

Comment: No problem, feel free to mark this as the accepted answer @Ken if it answered your question also.